# Can anyone explain why this JavaScript causes memory leaks in IE7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, dom-events

The code is rather long yet simple:

- 100 leaky JavaScript objects are created.
- 10 leaky elements are created from the JS objects.
- 1 element is removed and 1 is added 10000 times.

I assume that the `detachEvent` call is not functioning properly.
Also, if you change `this.eventParams` from an array to a simple variable, the leak goes away. Why?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Memory Leak With Fix</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .leakyEle 
      {
        border: solid 1px red;
        background-color: Gray;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
/******************************* MAIN ********************************/
var leakObjArray = new Array();
AddEvent(window, 'load', Startup, false);

function Startup() {           
  for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    leakObjArray.push(new LeakyObj(i));
  }
  
  for(var j=0; j<10; j++) {
    leakObjArray[j].CreateLeakyEle();
  }     
  var container = document.getElementById('Container');
  AddEvent(container, 'click', Run, false);
  alert('Close this dialog and click the document to continue.');
}

function Run() {
  var k = 0;
  var l = 10;
  
  for(var m = 0; m<10000; m++) {
    leakObjArray[k].DestroyLeakyEle();
    leakObjArray[l].CreateLeakyEle();
    if(k<leakObjArray.length - 1) {
      k++;
    } else {
      k = 0;
    }
    if(l<leakObjArray.length - 1) {
      l++;
    } else {
      l = 0;
    }
  }   
  for(var i=0; i<leakObjArray.length; i++) {
    leakObjArray[i].DestroyLeakyEle();
  }
  alert('Test Complete.');
}

/******************************* END MAIN ********************************/

/******************************* LEAKY OBJECT ********************************/
function LeakyObj(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.leakyEle = null;
  this.containerEle = document.getElementById('Container');
  this.clicked = false;
  this.eventParams = new Array();
}

LeakyObj.prototype.CreateLeakyEle = function() {
  var leakyEle = document.createElement('div');
  leakyEle.id = 'leakyEle' + this.id;  
  leakyEle.className = 'leakyEle';           
  leakyEle.innerHTML = this.id + ' --- XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' +
    '<br/>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' +
    '<br/>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' +
    '<br/>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' +
    '<br/>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
   
  this.leakyEle = leakyEle;
  
  var _self = this;
  this.eventParams.push(AddEventWithReturnParams(this.leakyEle, 'click', function() { _self.EventHandler(); }, false));
  
  this.containerEle.appendChild(leakyEle);
}

LeakyObj.prototype.DestroyLeakyEle = function() {
  if(this.leakyEle != null) {
    this.containerEle.removeChild(this.leakyEle);
    for(var i=0; i<this.eventParams.length; i++) {      
      RemoveEventOverload(this.eventParams[i]);
    }
    this.leakyEle = null;
  }
}

LeakyObj.prototype.EventHandler = function() {
  this.leakyEle.style.display = 'none';
  this.clicked = true;
}

/******************************* END LEAKY OBJECT ********************************/

/******************************* GENERAL FUNCS ********************************/
    
function AddEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture){
  var success = false;
  if(elm.addEventListener) {
    if(evType == 'mousewheel') evType = 'DOMMouseScroll';
    elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);    
    success = true;
  } else if(elm.attachEvent) {
    if(evType == 'mousewheel') {
      window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = fn;
      success = true;
    } else {
      var r = elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
      success = r;
    }
  } else {
    success = false;
  }
  elm = null;
  return success;
}

function AddEventWithReturnParams(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
  var eventParams = new EventParams(elm, evType, fn, useCapture);
  AddEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture);
  return eventParams;
}

function RemoveEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
  if(elm) {  
  if(elm.removeEventListener) {
    elm.removeEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);    
    return true;
  } else if(elm.detachEvent) {  
    var r = elm.detachEvent('on' + evType, fn);    
    return r;
  } else {
    debugger;
  }  
  }
}

function RemoveEventOverload(eventParams) {
  if(eventParams) {
    return RemoveEvent(eventParams.element, eventParams.eventType, eventParams.handler, eventParams.capture);
  }
}

function EventParams(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
  return {
    element: elm,
    eventType: evType,
    handler: fn,
    capture: useCapture
  }
}
/******************************* END GENERAL FUNCS ********************************/
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you're pushing stuff onto the eventParams array inside CreateLeakyEle, but never removing it?  Is that right?

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at your code, you should notice that in each eventParams object stored in your eventParams array, you have references to the objects, but you never empty out your array.  Try clearing out your array...